# How get a dictionary dynamically?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, dictionary

I have a `for i in range(1,80):` with the size 80 and there is a dictionary `index = {}` in my `for` loop. I want for each time that my `for` loop circle, adds a key-value equal to `i` and type value equal to a list.

I also tried this code:

```
import numpy as np

 index  = {}
 for i in range(1, 80):
      tmp = L * msk
      (r, c) = np.nonzero(tmp > 0)
      v = np.size(c)  # v equal 24
      I = np.arange(v) # I = [0,1,2,3,...,23]
      Ind = np.empty((v, 2))
      Ind[i , :] = (r[I[i]], c[I[I]])
      index = {key = I: type = Ind}
```

Comment: key must be i not I

Comment: Please show your expected output. Instead of 80 make it 10 though for simplcity. Thanks. Did you want `d = {i: [] for i in range(1, 80)}`? It's sort of unusual to use a dict for sequential numbers like this. A list is faster and more semantic. Also, a `defaultdict(list)` is possibly better for whatever it is you're trying to do if you do need a dict... I'm not sure what the numpy code has to do with the text you asked about, though.

Comment: thank you for your list thing explanation it's really helped me

Answer (score 1):

In the last line, you're changing the entire `index` reference to a new dictionary. You need to add a new key to `index`, not change it entirely. Try changing that line to:

```py
index[i] = Ind
```

Comment: There are other issues with your code, but you didn't ask about those other issues, you asked how to add to the dictionary on each iteration.